# Should we add a [css-transform] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

So I was just looking around and learned about [tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms). Looks like there's one that could be added, so I went ahead and tried to suggest it (just for the sake of getting that Synonymizer badge, admittedly).

However, I got this error instead:

> Failed to propose synonym:
>
> The suggested tag must exist in the system before suggesting it as a
>   synonym!

So I went to edit one question and tried adding the tag first. But I got another error:

[image: error]

Also I noticed there are many `css-*` tags that could be improved in a similar way—most notably [css-float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-float) doesn't have a [css-floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-floats) synonym tag.

Should the [css-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-transform) tag be allowed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[css-transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-transforms) already exists. There is no need for another tag that is essentially the singular version of the plural. And the site usually rejects suggesting singulars as synonyms of plurals or vice versa.

The tag is in plural to reflect the name of the spec, CSS Transforms. Most tags that represent CSS3 specs (that usually encapsulate a large number of properties and/or features) have names that reflect either the proper name, or the URL slug as seen in the spec's w3.org/TR URL.

[css-float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-float) is a little different. There is no floats spec, so it defaults to the property name instead. And the similarly named [css-clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-clear) is a synonym.